# cURL settings in debian

Tags: php, curl, xampp, debian

I recently setup a cURL script, which I tested at a Windows XAMPP environment.
Now I want to bring it live on our Debian machine, but its not working anyhow.

I think this has something to do with the php5 cURL settings, but I can't get it to work.
This is the output of the php information on the Windows machine:

[image]

This is the output of the php information of the Debian machine:

[image]

This is the code that works on the Windows machine, but doesn't work on Debian:

```
 <?php

// Begin unifi authorisatie

session_start();

function sendAuthorization($id, $minutes)
{
    $unifiServer = "https://127.0.0.1:8443"; // unifi server
    $unifiUser = "admin"; // unifi admin naam
    $unifiPass = "xxxxxx"; // unifi admin wachtwoord

    // Start Curl for login
    $ch = curl_init();
    // We are posting data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    // Set up cookies
    $cookie_file = "/tmp/unifi_cookie";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    // Allow Self Signed Certs
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    // Force TLSv1 only
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
    // Login to the UniFi controller
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "login=login&username=$unifiUser&password=$unifiPass");
    // send login command
    curl_exec ($ch);

    // Send user to authorize and the time allowed
    $data = json_encode(array(
        'cmd'=>'authorize-guest',
        'mac'=>$id,
        'minutes'=>$minutes));

    // Send the command to the API
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/api/s/default/cmd/stamgr'); // Vergeet de site niet aan te passen bij een nieuwe locatie
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data);
    curl_exec ($ch);

    // Logout of the UniFi Controller
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/logout');
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    unset($ch);
}

if ($_SESSION['loggingin'] == "unique key") // Check to see if the form has been posted to
{
    ob_start();
        sendAuthorization($_SESSION['id'], (180*24*60)); //authorizing user for 180 days
    ob_end_clean();
    unset($_SESSION['loggingin']);
}

?>
```

I think it has something to do with the https protocol that's missing, but how do I install it for cURL?

Comment: does it give you any errors ? what is your `/tmp/unifi_cookie` ? do you have access on `/tmp` folder ?

Comment: I see that you try to access the url via `https` and your debian server do not support `ssl`. The code seems fine.

Comment: @Alex I have acces on the /tmp folder, I also thought there was a problem with https, is there any way on installing this. Bear in mind that I'm not a linux expert, so please forgive me for this stupid question :)

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question in https://serverfault.com , or try to install `libssl` libraries.